# Return all values from 'for' loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataSets.length; i++) {
        var result = _.filter(data, function(item){
          return _.contains(item, dataSets[i]);
        });
        var collection = []
        for(x in result)collection.push(result[x].value);
    }
```

When I do a console.log(collection) inside the method, I can see 3 arrays, which is correct.

```
[431, 552, 318, 332, 185]
[17230, 17658, 15624, 16696, 9276]
[5323, 6359, 8216, 9655, 5513]
```

However outside of the method I can only get the last value.

```
[5323, 6359, 8216, 9655, 5513]
```

Is there a way I can return **all** the values outside of the method?

Comment: define an external "collectionArray" (outside of the for scope) and push the collection into it after. Or use the map function of dataSets, assuming it's an array and that you use a relatively modern browser)

Comment: your collection[] array gets overwritten on each iteration of for...loop so move it out of for...loop and it should work..

Comment: Don't use [`for in` loops](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add each collection to an array:

```
var collections = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dataSets.length; i++) {
    var result = _.filter(data, function(item){
      return _.contains(item, dataSets[i]);
    });
    collections[i] = [];
    for(x in result) collections[i].push(result[x].value);
}
// Now you have all values into "collections"
// If you are within a method you can also "return collections;" here
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in an ES6 state of mind:

```
dataSets . map(set => data .
    filter(item => item.contains(set)) .
    map   (item => item.value)
)
```